# How to share my app script to other spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have done my app script for test google sheet.
Now I want to import this app script in another google sheet.
I can copy all code to new app script,
but it seems not a good way and a little stupid.
Is there any better way?

Comment: Have you looked at building an add-on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options

1. [Build a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries), this will allow you to easily integrate your code in any spreadsheet
2. [Build an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/overview); this is slightly more complex, but will allow your users to use a UI to run your scripts without ever needing to use an editor. In your case it's probably best to use this option if you have a Workspace account, this way you can build a private add-on

Comment: I have some time trigger events, can I add these events to add-on?

Comment: yes, no problem